# An alternative to redis transactions for atomicity in node

Tags: node.js, redis, atomic, node-redis

I have an express webserver that performs some operations, in Redis, which need to be atomic, on a key whose value is a list. More specifically, this is more or less the structure of my code

```
redisclient.lrange(key, 0, -1 (error, items) => {
    .
    .
    .
    //some slightly complex code that updates the list of strings
    //obtain newItems from items
    .
    .
    .
    redisclient.del(key);
    //push the newly updated list
    for (let item of newItems){
        redisclient.rpush(key,item);
    }
});
```

The problem here is that, from my understanding, in order to make these operations atomic I would need to use a Lua script. I don't know anything about Lua though, and converting my JS logic in a Lua script wouldn't be trivial.

Node is single-threaded, but isn't there any alternative to avoid race conditions between different clients in a code like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a transaction so that the DEL and RPUSH commands are executed atomically. See [CLIENT.MULTI([COMMANDS])](http://redis.js.org/#api-clientmulticommands).

You can add a WATCH for your key if you want the transaction not to execute if your list was modified while you processed it. See [OPTIMISTIC LOCKS](http://redis.js.org/#api-optimistic-locks). But here, you need recovery/retry logic in case it fails.

To use `WATCH`, you first start watching, then read the list with `LRANGE`, do your manipulation, then do `MULTI`, `DEL`, `RPUSH`, `EXEC`. The EXEC will fail if the list was modified between `WATCH` and `EXEC`.

```
client.watch(key, function( err ){
    if(err) throw err;

    client.lrange(key, 0, -1, function(err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;

        // Process the result

        client.multi()
            .del(key)
            .rpush(key, newItems)
            .exec(function(err, results) {

                /**
                 * If err is null, it means Redis successfully attempted 
                 * the operation.
                 */ 
                if(err) throw err;

                /**
                 * If results === null, it means that a concurrent client
                 * changed the key while we were processing it and thus 
                 * the execution of the MULTI command was not performed.
                 * 
                 * NOTICE: Failing an execution of MULTI is not considered
                 * an error. So you will have err === null and results === null
                 */
            });
    });
});
```

`RPUSH` in Redis supports multiple elements at once. Consider pushing multiple elements at once by using the `[send_command][3]` directly, [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), or passing the array directly (depends on what version are you running).

That said, consider using Lua scripts. Here a little push to get you started:

```
EVAL "local list1 = redis.call('LRANGE', KEYS[1], 0, -1) for ix,elm in ipairs(list1) do list1[ix] = string.gsub(elm, 'node', 'nodejs') end redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1]) redis.call('RPUSH', KEYS[1], unpack(list1)) return list1" 1 myList
```

Here a friendly view of the Lua script:

```
local list1 = redis.call('LRANGE', KEYS[1], 0, -1)
for ix,elm in ipairs(list1) do
    list1[ix] = string.gsub(elm, 'node', 'nodejs')
end
redis.call('DEL', KEYS[1])
redis.call('RPUSH', KEYS[1], unpack(list1))
return list1
```

This simply replaces `node` by `nodejs` in all elements of the list. See more on  string manipulation at the [String Library Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial).

Comment: So to clarify, I should leave lrange as it is, then set up a watch for the key and use a transaction for del and rpush?

Comment: @Plutone11011, I just expanded the answer on optimistic locking. You first start watching, otherwise, the list may change between `LRANGE` and `WATCH`. I also added a little invitation for Lua scripting